# Evaluating a 2d Gaussian distribution along a line

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, gaussian, kalman-filter

I have a 2d multi-variate gaussian distribution is intersected somewhere by a straight line. I would now like to evaluate the 2d Gaussian along this one line. If I'm not mistaken, this should be a simple 1d gaussian in a coordinate (let's call it s) going along the line?

How would I compute this?
Specifically I'm working in Python/Numpy. Very generally speaking, I'm working on Kalman Filters.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: To help others help you, please share any relevant code you may have and your attempts.

Comment: you might try looking into how to calculate the chord of an ellipse or (hyper-)ellipsoid - that should let you find the standard deviation along s, as well as the mean and amplitude.

Comment: As you know, that's a conditional distribution, and it is again Gaussian. You might want to take a look at the discussion of conditional distributions derived from multidimensonal Gaussian distributions in, I think, Chapter VIII of "Mathematical Theory of Probability and Statistics" by Richard von Mises. You can probably work out a formula for the distribution you mentioned by rotating the line to be axis-aligned and then going from there.

Answer (score 0):

To get the restriction of the probability density function of a bivariate normal distribution you can use its definition from `scipy.stats`:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal as BN
import plotly.graph_objects as go

meanv=[0.5, -0.2]
Sigma=np.array([[1.5, 0.6], [0.6, 1.75]])
rv = BN(meanv, Sigma)
x = np.linspace(meanv[0]-3*np.sqrt(Sigma[0,0]), meanv[0]+3*np.sqrt(Sigma[0,0]), 100)
y= np.linspace(meanv[1]-3*np.sqrt(Sigma[1,1]), meanv[1]+3*np.sqrt(Sigma[1,1]), 100)
xv, yv = np.meshgrid(x,y)
pos = np.dstack((xv, yv))
z= rv.pdf(pos)

fig=go.Figure(go.Surface(x=x, y=y, z=z, colorscale=[[0, '#90ee90'], [1.0, '#90ee90']],
                                                    showscale=False))
X= np.linspace(-2, 2, 150)
Y= 2*X-0.7
Z=rv.pdf(np.dstack((X,Y)))  #Restriction of pdf to the given line
fig.add_scatter3d(x=X, y=Y, z=Z+0.001, mode="lines", line_width=2, line_color="black")
fig.update_layout(width=600, height=500, font_size=11, scene_camera_eye=dict(x=-1.6, y=1.6, z=1))
```

[image: Gaussianpdf-restricted-to-a-line]

Note that you must provide the mean vector of the bivariate normal distribution and its covariance matrix, Sigma.
`rv = BN(meanv, Sigma)` defines a random variable having the distribution of given mean and covariance, and rv.pdf is its probability density function.
The line  is considered as being included within the plane z=0, such that it intersect the domain where the pdf is not very close to zero.